# jQuery selector $("input[with="+id+"]")

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does this jQuery selector actually work ?

`$("input[with="+id+"]")`

Used inside this function :

```
function enableFields(id) {
    $("input[with="+id+"]").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', false);
    });   
}
```

Would it be correct to say "select all `input` elements who have a `with` attribute.  On the current `input` element, set the `with` attribute value to the value of the current element's `id` attribute" ?

Essentially, if the input element looks like `<input id="idValue" with="withValue">`, momentarily set the `with` attribute to the value from `id` which would look `<input id="idValue" with="idValue">` and use it to select the element to call `each()` on?

Comment: It's a selector, you're not changing anything.  If you prefer, think of it as `[with===id]`

Comment: The above code that takes an `id`, finds all the `input` tags with an attribute `with` that has the value of `id` and sets their disabled attributes to false.

Comment: "Would it be correct to say... " - no, that's not correct at all.

Comment: And what I said it does above is only vaguely correct.  Because id isn't encoded or escaped, I interpreted what I believe to have been the intention of it, but it could also be abused depending on the value of id.  Such as if the value of id was... `a],*,*[` would enable every tag on the page.  Even those that aren't input tags.

Comment: Since Id's are to be UNIQUE you should only need to do $('#' + id).attr('disabled', false) but you shouldn't even do that since most browsers ignore the false and take the presence of disabled as disabled. so you want to instead use: removeAttr('disabled'). Do not use each. There is no need to use each since you are only targeting a specific input.

Comment: @Adrianopolis You meant to say `$('#'+id)`, not `$(id)`.

Comment: Yep David I caught that.

Answer (score 0):

Only use each if targeting multiple inputs to update. Using an id vs a classname leads me to think youre intnetion is to do a single input update at a time. Do not use disabled false anymore since most modern browsers interpret the presence of disabled as "disabled". If you want to update multiple inputs use className selector instead of id.

Keeping in the spirit of a unique id:

```
function enableFields(id) {
    $("#" + id).removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Update multiple inputs using a className:

```
function enableFields(className) {
    $("." + className).each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    });   
}
```